# Cell Position Using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I have data in `List<List<string>> data`. I want to locate the cell position using LINQ. Like I have 3 columns and 5 rows and my desired values is available at 1st columns and 3rd row. Please tell me the solution how I can achieve this using LINQ in C#. I want the functionality like excel where it highlights the data cell on find.

Answer (score 3):

You won't gain anything here using LINQ.  Just index into the lists.

```
var cell = data[3][1];
```

Otherwise,

```
var cell = data.ElementAt(3).ElementAt(1);
```